# Question Regarding Nvidia GPU drivers and how Linux auto-loads them

Tags: linux-kernel, boot, drivers, nvidia, proprietary-drivers

I have built a portable Linux installation on USB. In my pursuit of working on all x86_64 systems,I have successfully got it to work in both BIOS and UEFI environments, and also added Mac-specific wifi drivers and got them to work. I want to clear the roadblock of GPUs.

So what I'm specifically looking to know is that if I install Nvidia drivers, this means that the kernel will auto-load these when booting from a system using an Nvidia GPU, correct ? This will still mean that I can boot from an IntelHD or AMD system flawlessly, and just as from a clean Linux install, correct ?

Needless to say, this question may be obvious and very stupid, but I'm a noob and need guidance.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So what I'm specifically looking to know is that if I install Nvidia drivers, this means that the kernel will auto-load these when booting from a system using an Nvidia GPU, correct ?

Correct.

> This will still mean that I can boot from an IntelHD or AMD system flawlessly, and just as from a clean Linux install, correct ?

Not necessarily. At least in the past NVIDIA drivers used to overwrite parts of the X.org and Mesa stacks and in the process made them unusable for AMD and Intel. Something might have changed recently but I cannot vouch for that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! However, I have already installed driver version 440 on my Lubuntu 20.04 install, and am able to boot into my intelHD machine no issues